# How can I count different values per same key with Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a code which is able to give me the list like this:

```
  Name  id number week number
    Piata   4            6    
    Mali    2          20,5    
    Goerge  5           4    
    Gooki   3         24,64,6   
    Mali    5          45,9
    Piata   6           1    
    Piata  12          2,7,8,27,16 etc..
```

with the below code:

```
import csv
from datetime import date

datedict = defaultdict(set)
with open('d:/info.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.reader(csvfile, 'excel')
    #passing the header
    read_header = False
    start_date=date(year=2009,month=1,day=1)
    #print((seen_date - start_date).days)
    tdic = {}
    for row in filereader: 
        if not read_header:
            read_header = True
            continue

    # reading the rest rows
        name,id,firstseen = row[0],row[1],row[3]
        try:
            seen_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstseen, '%d/%m/%Y').date()               
            deltadays = (seen_date-start_date).days
            deltaweeks = deltadays/7 + 1
            key = name,id
            currentvalue = tdic.get(key, set())
            currentvalue.add(deltaweeks)
            tdic[key] = currentvalue

        except ValueError:
            print('Date value error')
            pass
```

Right now I want to convert my list to a list that give me number of ids for each name and its weeks numbers like the below list:

```
Name     number of ids      weeknumbers
Mali         2                20,5,45,9
Piata        3               1,6,2,7,8,27,16
Goerge       1                   4
Gooki        1                 24,64,6
```

Can anyone help me with writing the code for this part?

Comment: Your CSV input file d:/info.csv shouldn't have a coma-separated style ? What is defaultdict(set) ? is it equal to {} ?

Comment: @Mikael Mayer The input is fine. it works and default(Set)={}

Comment: Can you provide an input file ? I did not understand that the first file you provided was the output.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post either the `info.csv` file or a representative sample of it?  From your recent questions it feels like you're reinventing the kinds of data manipulations that a tool like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) is good at.

Answer (score 0):

givent that :

```
tdict = {('Mali', 5): set([9, 45]), ('Gooki', 3): set([24, 64, 6]), ('Goerge', 5): set([4]), ('Mali', 2): set([20, 5]), ('Piata', 4): set([4]), ('Piata', 6): set([1]), ('Piata', 12): set([8, 16, 2, 27, 7])}
```

then to output the result above:

```
names = {}
for ((name, id), more_weeks) in tdict.items():
  (ids, weeks) = names.get(name, (0, set()))
  ids = ids + 1
  weeks = weeks.union(more_weeks)
  names[name] = (ids, weeks)

for (name, (id, weeks)) in names.items():
  print("%s, %s, %s" % (name, id, weeks)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like your csv file has headers (which you are currently ignoring) why not use a [`DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) instead of the standard `reader` class? If you don't supply fieldnames the `DictReader` will assume the first line contains them, which will also save you from having to skip the first line in your loop.

This seems like a great opportunity to use `defaultdict` and `Counter` from the `collections` module.

```
import csv
from datetime import date
from collections import defaultdict, Counter


datedict = defaultdict(set)
namecounter = Counter()
with open('d:/info.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    filereader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    start_date=date(year=2009,month=1,day=1)

    for row in filereader: 
        name,id,firstseen = row['name'], row['id'], row['firstseen']

        try:
            seen_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(firstseen, '%d/%m/%Y').date() 
        except ValueError:
            print('Date value error')
            pass

        deltadays = (seen_date-start_date).days
        deltaweeks = deltadays/7 + 1

        datedict[name].add(deltaweeks)
        namecounter.update([name])  # Without putting name into a list, update will index each character
```

This assumes that `(name, id)` is unique. If this is not the case then you can use another`defaultdict` for `namecounter`. I've also moved the try-except statement so it is more explicit in what you are testing.